# JQuery Run Javascript on dialog load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jira

I've written some Javascript for a JIRA instance that automatically fills a field when creating an issue. It works just as expected if I open the 'Create Issue' screen in a new window. 
However, when 'Create Issue' appears in a dialog box, my script doesn't run.
How would I enable my script to run when the 'Create Issue' dialog screen opens in a window?
Below is my code:

```
/*
 * Automatically fills the summary field of an issue and hides the field at issue creation.
*/

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e,context) {
    autoFillSummary();
});

autoFillSummary();

// Automatically fill the summary field with a default value.
function autoFillSummary(){
    var issueType = $('#issue-create-issue-type').text();
    var reporter = $('#reporter').val();
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.toDateString();
    var summaryVal = reporter + " - " + "[ " + d + " ]";
    if(issueType === "Job"){
        $('#summary').val(summaryVal);
        $('#summary').closest('div.field-group').hide();
        $('#reporter').closest('div.field-group').hide();
    }
}  

});
```

The id for the dialog is **create-issue-dialog**
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 3):

i would do it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#create-issue-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function(e, context) {
        autoFillSummary();
      });
    }
  });

  // Automatically fill the summary field with a default value.
  function autoFillSummary() {
    var issueType = $('#issue-create-issue-type').text();
    var reporter = $('#reporter').val();
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.toDateString();
    var summaryVal = reporter + " - " + "[ " + d + " ]";
    if (issueType === "Job") {
      $('#summary').val(summaryVal);
      $('#summary').closest('div.field-group').hide();
      $('#reporter').closest('div.field-group').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

<sub>*I have not used JIRA ever.*</sub>

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the solution but thanks for the help and the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```
AJS.toInit(function () {
    autoFillSummary();
});

JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e,context) {
    autoFillSummary();
});

// Automatically fill the summary field with a default value.
function autoFillSummary(){
    var issueType = $('#issue-create-issue-type').text();
    var reporter = $('#reporter').val();
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.toDateString();
    var summaryVal = reporter + " - " + "[ " + d + " ]";
    if(issueType === "Job"){
        $('#summary').val(summaryVal);
        $('#summary').closest('div.field-group').hide();
        $('#reporter').closest('div.field-group').hide();
    }
}
```

Try to add AJS.toInit(function () { ... }); it runs your script in create issue form

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet been able to find an ideal solution but as a work-around, I have been able to disable the dialog from appearing and forcing the screen to load into a new page:

```
/*
 * Automatically fills the summary field of an issue and hides the field at issue creation.
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Disable pop-up window - Forces 'Create Issue' to load in new page.
AJS.$("#create_link").removeClass("create-issue");

autoFillSummary();

// Automatically fill the summary field with a default value.
function autoFillSummary(){
    var issueType = AJS.$('#issue-create-issue-type').text();
    var reporter = AJS.$('#reporter').val();
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.toDateString();
    var summaryVal = reporter + " - " + "[ " + d + " ]";
    if(issueType === "Job"){
        AJS.$('#summary').val(summaryVal);
        AJS.$('#summary').closest('div.field-group').hide();
        AJS.$('#reporter').closest('div.field-group').hide();
    }
}  
});
```

If anyone figures out a way to avoid disabling the dialog it would be much appreciated.